# JQUERY toggle for change price and order link

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I'am try do the follow, by using the follow query change the display prices and direct link for order.

```
function changepricing() {
    jQuery("#monthly").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#monthly1").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#montly2").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#monthly3").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#monthly4").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#halfyear").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#halfyear1").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#halfyear2").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#halfyear3").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#halfyear4").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#annual").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#annual1").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#annual2").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#annual3").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#annual4").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#biannual").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#biannual1").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#biannual2").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#biannual3").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#biannual4").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcmonthly1").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcmonthly2").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcmonthly3").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcmonthly4").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prchalfyear1").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prchalfyear2").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prchalfyear3").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prchalfyear4").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcannual1").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcannual2").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcannual3").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcannual4").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcbiannual1").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcbiannual2").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcbiannual3").slideToggle();
    jQuery("#prcbiannual4").slideToggle();
}
```

Is the code

For show and change prices:

```
    <li id="monthly" class="pricing_header2" style="display:block;"><a href="#" onclick="changepricing();return false;"><span>1 Month </span></a></li>
    <li id="halfyear" class="pricing_header2" style="display:none;"><a href="#" onclick="changepricing();return false;"><span>6 Months </span></a></li>
    <li id="annual" class="pricing_header2" style="display:none;"><a href="#" onclick="changepricing();return false;"><span>{$LANG.product_choose_one} </span></a></li>
    <li id="biannual" class="pricing_header2" style="display:none;"><a href="#" onclick="changepricing();return false;"><span>{$LANG.product_choose_two} </span></a></li>
```

For display prices and order links:

```
        <li id="monthly1" class="pricing_header2" style="display:block;">&euro;1 <span>/1 mo.</span></li>
        <li id="halfyear1" class="pricing_header2" style="display:none;">&euro;2 <span>/6 mos.</span></li>
        <li id="annual1" class="pricing_header2" style="display:none;">&euro;3 <span>/One yr.</span></li>
        <li id="biannual1" class="pricing_header2" style="display:none;">&euro;4 <span>/Two yrs.</span></li>

        <li id="prcmonthly1" class="pricing_footer" style="display:block;"><span><a href="link1" class="pricing_button">{$LANG.product_buy_now}</a></li>
        <li id="prchalfyear1" class="pricing_footer" style="display:none;"><span><a href="link2" class="pricing_button">{$LANG.product_buy_now}</a></li>
        <li id="prcannual1" class="pricing_footer" style="display:none;"><span><a href="link3" class="pricing_button">{$LANG.product_buy_now}</a></li>
        <li id="prcbiannual1" class="pricing_footer" style="display:none;"><span><a href="link4" class="pricing_button">{$LANG.product_buy_now}</a></li>
```

The Above code work fine if I use only for 2 products but by using 3 or 4 products not work. Can any give a help? I really appreciate.

Thanks,
Manuel

Comment: You will have to indent the javascript code, for us to try and understand it

Comment: Your changepricing method kind of gives me a head ache but you can propably clean it up a bit by selecting via class instead. Something like $(".pricing_header2").slideToggle();

Comment: Hi,pricing_header is from CSS sheet and not from jquery. The code for jquery is: e.g id="monthly1". The same code work for two product but not work for 4. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whoa!

May I suggest putting another class on the toggle-able items (eg `<li class='pricing_header2 toggleable'>`) and using this JS code instead:

```
 $('.toggleable').slideToggle();
```

Comment: Hi, as I tel above the id is the change class"pricing_header2" is the style of table from CSS. I pretend is: as here: http://www.kanumhost.com/ssl-certificates is two products. Work here http://www.kanumhost.com/reseller.php whit four products. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set of those divs for each product than I'm really wandering how it's working for 2 prods? Any way as Mikael Härsjö said, use classes instead of ids when working with lists of items. You cannot have more that one div id="foo" but you can have unlimited div class="foo".

So, I managed to scrape up this function:

```
function changepricing(_from, _to) {
  for(i=0; i<=4; i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
      nr = '';
    }
    else {
      nr = i;
    }
    jQuery("#"+_from+nr).slideToggle();
    jQuery("#"+_to+nr).slideToggle();
  }
}
```

In order to make it work you'll have to make the call with like this:

```
<li id="monthly" class="pricing_header2" style="display: block;">
  <a onclick="changepricing('monthly', 'halfyear');return false;" href="#">
    <span>1 Month </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please give a example working of code I need add for this work? Many thanks all

Comment: Hi, I have change all to use of class but still not work, please take a look here: http://www.kanumhost.com/reseller.php Not change display of price but hide for one month and show halfyear, one year and two year. What can be wrong? Many thanks

Comment: Many things can go wrong with that design but I managed to scrape up the function from the answer. Take a look at the modified answer above.